# Property binding to a service function - angular

Tags: angular

Is it possible to bind a property to a service function?

I am trying something like this:

View:

```
<app-grid [header]=namingConventionService.getResourceText("something")></app-grid>
```

In the Service:

```
getResourceText(key: string) {
if (this.namingConvention) {
  return this.namingConvention[key];
}
```

}

I get a console error: Template parse errors: Unexpected closing tag...

Comment: `[header]="namingConventionService.getResourceText('something')"` you missed the quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose the binding in double quotes, and the inner string in single quotes:

```
[header]="namingConventionService.getResourceText('something')"
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, try enclosing the function in quotes.

```html
<app-grid [header]="namingConventionService.getResourceText('something')"></app-grid>
```

Notice the single quotes surrounding `something`. That is how constant literals are used in templates.